# How to delete a line from a file if it contains certain data

Tags: python, file

I have made this program on python so that it will ask the user for their name, before searching the file for their name. It will then print the line number(s) on which their name is found. I want the program to delete the lines that the name is on - (all except the most recent 3). Is this possible?

Comment: I suspect that you wanted to know more than if it is possible.  You should reword your question to describe the problem that you have

Comment: count how many times you have seen the name,  if the count is over 3  remove those lines using a tempfile to write to and replace original with temp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to keep the most recent additions:

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from shutil import move

def keep_three(fle):
    name = input("Please enter your name")
    with open(fle, 'r+') as f,  NamedTemporaryFile("w",dir=".", delete=False) as out:
        # find indexes for all occurrences  of the name
        indexes = [ind for ind, line in enumerate(f) if line.strip() == name]   
        # if there are less than 3 occurrences then write the name
        if len(indexes) < 3:
            f.write("{}\n".format(name))
            return 
        elif len(indexes) == 3:
            return 
        # else use the earliest indexes less than the last three
        f.seek(0) # go back to startof file
        remove = set(indexes[:len(indexes) -3])
        for ind, line in enumerate(f):
            # only write the lines we don't want to ignore
            if ind not in remove:
                out.write(line)
     # replace the original file
     move(out.name, fle)
```

You might be better off using a different structure to keep the names  in, using a dict and pickling might be a better option.
You could use a Counter dict to get a count but that will not give you the indexes so probably not much use.

You could also use [fileinput.input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) with `inplace=True` to modify the original file:

```
import fileinput
import sys

def keep_three(fle):   
    name = input("Please enter your name")
    with open(fle, 'r+') as f:
        indexes = [ind for ind, line in enumerate(f) if line.strip() == name]
        if len(indexes) < 3:
            f.write("{}\n".format(name))
            return
        elif len(indexes) == 3:
            return 
        remove = set(indexes[:len(indexes)-3])
        for ind, line in enumerate(fileinput.input(fle,inplace=True)):
            if ind not in remove:
                sys.stdout.write(line)
```

But again I think a different way of storing the names would be best or at least grouping the names together in your file.

Comment: Thank you for the useful input however I am unable to use this since I am from England and therefore it says that this is an invalid file. I cannot open a file in r or r+

Comment: @arun, I don't think python discriminates based on where you are from! What happens exactly?

Comment: python says this:    with open(fle, 'r+') as f:
TypeError: invalid file: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='Class 1.txt' mode='r' encoding='US-ASCII'>

Comment: I wrote with open ("Class 1.txt") as fle. In the program.

Comment: So you are not using the functions?

Comment: I am using the functions

Comment: so `keep_three("Class 1.txt"))` gives you that error?

Comment: yes but did you run the code with `keep_three("Class 1.txt"))`? I have run the code with no issues at all, you have to be doing something incorrectly.